# Torsion tensor definition (Lee) in terms of tensors (or multilinear maps)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors

John M. Lee (Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature) defines torsion field as a map $\tau : \mathcal{T}(M)\times\mathcal{T}(M)\rightarrow\mathcal{T}(M)$ where ($\mathcal{T}(M)$ is a set of vector fields, won't write complete definition because it's not important) and calls it a $\binom{2}{1}$ tensor.

How can we call it a tensor if a structure is not at all similar to his own definition of tensor in his previous book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"?

I mean in a sense that a $\binom{k}{l}$ tensor is an element of $\bigotimes_k V^*\bigotimes_l V$ or multilinear map $f:\times_kV\times_lV^*\rightarrow F$ where $F$ is a field (there is a bijection of these 2 structures, easy to prove).

I also know there is natural correspondence of $\binom{1}{1}$ tensors and $End(V)$ given by $\phi(A)(\omega,X)= \omega(AX)$.

Please help me find natural correspondence of $\binom{2}{1}$ tensors and $A:V\times V\rightarrow V$? I suppose A is multilinear? Can this be generalized to arbitrary $\binom{k}{l}$ tensors?

Comment: Try finding a correspondence between (1,1)-tensors and linear maps V\to V. Once you do that everything will be clear.

Comment: A slight expansion on Mariano's comment. This is essentially a question of linear algebra since it is pointwise. If you formalize everything, then relevant ideas here are "tensor-hom adjunction" and $V^{**}=V$.

Comment: I'd guess that $\tau(X, Y, \omega) = \langle \tau(X, Y), \omega \rangle$ is a good identification to make here.